# Is there a way to separate a MySql statement by space with a LIKE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT school WHERE school LIKE '%suny at albany%';
```

This will result in Suny at Albany.

If I were to type in:

```
SELECT school WHERE school LIKE '%suny albany%';
```

Returns nothing

Is there a way to separate the white space characters so that there are LIKE statements between them.

so that when I enter 'suny albany', it will return 'SUNY at Albany'. Like below :

```
SELECT school WHERE school LIKE '%suny%' AND school LIKE '%albany%';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `%` wildcard in the middle as well.

```
SELECT school WHERE school LIKE '%suny%albany%';
```

You could also leave a space around the `%` like

```
SELECT school WHERE school LIKE 'suny % albany';
```

to prevent matching super strings like `sunyys palbanys` or `sunyalbany`.

Answer (score 4):

Use another percentage sign instead of the space like so:

```
SELECT school WHERE school LIKE '%suny%albany%';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the variable text between the two target words to maximum one word, use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) with a regular expression:

```
SELECT school
WHERE name RLIKE 'suny (\\w+ )?albany';
```

This will match "suny albany", "suny at albany", but not "suny at the albany".